# Mapping a dataset to textfield inside UItableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, wsdl, uitextfield, stub

In my app, I am using some .net asmx services (as backend) to get some data and populating it on my views. In one of the modules, i need to edit and save the data which am getting from the services.In that am getting several rowkeyvalues and accordingly am creating those many row cells in my tableview, which consists two UItextfields as well, which displays some unique code and comments.

Now if I have to edit and save some fields, I need to map each one of those rowkeys to each row cell and after that am creating object which is basically the wsdl proxy class which I have generated using Sudzc and pass each dataset and serialize it to XML and POST it through SOAP.

The real problem here, am not getting how to map each unique rowkeys to each row cell and create unique dataset(which mainly contains other fields as well including rowkey) for each row and pass it to proxy object (WSDL stubs).

Comment: Give us some code on how you create the cell.

Comment: Hi Nick, am creating the cells subclassing UItableViewCell. With Xib its quite easy to do it. my tableviewcell has to Ivars (for two textfields)to show unique code and comments which am getting from the service. Sorry 2 say am now working on a windows m/c, so could share any code.

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question? it is hard to figure out what you are trying to achieve. One advise though, never think about the tableViewCell as part of the data/model. Do all your changes, edit, deletion on the dataModel and have the tableView reflect it. Don't try and couple a dataRow with a UITableVIew row, will just get messy and eventually go wrong.

Comment: @Ricki: yeah this question has become pretty messy,coz I too got messed up with this thing. Anyways my ques was the other way around, edit in tableviewcell and save it to dataModel (more like dynamic injection)and push it to remote service. The dataset is much of .Net kind of terms.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your problem, but there are 2 ways I can think of to map a row cell to something.
1. Each UITableViewCell is a subclass of UIView, and so it has a "tag" attribute, which is an int.
   You can set this and check it's value.
2. When a user taps a row, the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is called.  IndexPath.row is an int that gives the absolute row postiion within it's section (and if only one section, then in the whole table).

Usually, in cellForRowAtIndexPath: you fetch your backing data corresponding to the IndexPath.row and populate the cell.  You could also set the cell's tag at that point.

This ties together the row, the cell and the data.
Hope that helps.
-Mike

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for your post. but if you closely to my post you can see i mentioned the rows are created according 2 the no of rowkeys am getting from service. Lets say there are 15 rowkeys are coming from services, so 15 row cells are created, which am creating subclassing uitableviewcell.

Comment: So?  15 rows, 5000 rows each one can have a unique tag and cell.  What's the problem?  I mean that - I don't know what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Mike: Now am not bothering about didselectedrowatindex because am not using this delegate. If i edit something in textfield and comments field, i have save somewhere the data and create a dataset. Lets say this is for one row and similarly for rest 14 rows and corresponding 14 datasets. now all these 15 datasets,i need to pass to my proxy object which will serialize to xml and i ll pass this XML to SOAP and service will take care of it. I hope this is much clear to you now.

Comment: @manoj - your topic is "mapping a dataset to a textfield" - can you use the UITextField's tag attribute?  Maybe you need some hashing function to run your rowkey through to get a unique integer which you can then tag your field with.

Comment: @Mike: well okay that one thing I know how to resolve like you mentioned about the tag. But could you suggest any approach so that my class would be intelligent enough as soon as i change something in the textfields, it will create a dataset for me and save it for future use, till i hit the save button to submit to the remote service.

Comment: You need to implement the UITextFieldDelegate protocol.  You can detect when the field begins or ends editing, and you can be called for every keystroke.  From inside those methods you can create, maintain and save your datasets.  Of course you'll need to do a switch on the field's tag to know which dataset to use.

Comment: well..yeah that was my initial approach. Could you please suggest me any specific design pattern(other than singleton) to save the values of particular textfield and then retrive evrything at one go and pass it to proxy object.

Comment: You could store them all in an NSMutableDictionary based on the rowkey.  Then when it's time to build your xml, you can get it from there.  The view controller that controls the table could have this dictionary as an iVar.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Mike. I will implement and lets see whats pop up. Thanks again for your time.